# "Spoof" File Extension In Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to "spoof" the file extension of a file in bash for consumption by another program? I can think of doing some shell scripting and making lots of soft-links, but that isn't very scalable.

Let's imagine I have a program I'm trying to use that requires input files to be of a specific file extension, and it has no method of turning off this check.

Comment: Why should `g++` care for the file names extension? You type in or code a command, and it executes that command with whatever files you specified. File name extensions are a leftover of the 80th. They are not really relevant any more, except on MS-Windows systems. Modern systems determine file types on the file content, not on the name extension.

Comment: File extensions have no meaning in Linux and are solely meant as a suggestion to the file type.

Comment: There are a few tools that check (and care) though I think they shouldn't. `gzip`/etc. do. `bash` shell completion (and presumably other shell's completion code) cares as well. Graphical file managers and some generic file opener utilities will/might also care but that's another special case.

Comment: Many tools, such as `gzip`, can be told not to check by not giving them filenames at all -- `gzip <infile` doesn't know `infile`'s name (unlike `gzip infile`, which does).

Comment: CLANG's g++, at least, can accept `-` as a filename, and will then read source from stdin.

Comment: @arkascha, unfortunately, `g++` uses file extensions to determine what kind of file it's being given -- an object file to be linked, a source file to be compiled, etc. When passed `-` to read from stdin, it needs an extra argument (either `-e language` or `-X`) to tell it which processing phases to run, since it no longer has that hint.

Comment: how about symbolic link duplicates?

Comment: @TopGunCoder I'm trying to avoid soft-links if at all possible.

Comment: Creating a symbolic link is probably the simplest way to do that.

Comment: @KeithThompson I suspect that's the only real/reasonable solution, but I had to ask anyway!

Comment: If you don't want to use symlinks, then you could accomplish this with a FUSE filesystem. (For example, such a filesystem might translate paths of the form `.../<name>/<name>.newext` to `.../<name>.oldext`. Or it could use a mapping table or even a database.) In practice, however, there are very few unix programs which really *insist* on a particular extension, and the ones which have some mechanism which depends on the file's extension (like `gcc`) normally provide some mechanism to override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symbolic link for each file you want to have a particular extension, then pass the name of the symlink to the command.

For example suppose you have files with names of the form `*.foo` and you need to refer to them with extensions of `.bar`:

```
for file in *.foo ; do
    ln -s $file _$$_$file.bar
done
```

I precede each symlink name with `_$$_` to avoid the possibility of colliding with an existing file name (you don't want to do `ln -s file.foo file.bar` if `file.bar` already exists).

With a little more programming, your script can keep track of which symlinks it created and, if you like, clean them up after executing the command.

This assumes, as you stated in the question, that the command can't be forced to accept a different extension.

You could, without too much difficulty, create a wrapper script that replaces the command in question, creating the symlinks, invoking the command, and cleaning up after itself automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a fifo with the requisite extension and `cat` any other file type into it. So, if your crazy program needs to see files that end in `.funky`, you can do this:

```
mkfifo file.funky
cat someotherfile > file.funky &
someprogram file.funky
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of a fifo. But I'm going to accept the other answer as it's much more scalable. Dog help you if you have to do this for 1000s of files!